# How to extend JFrame and JPanel in a main class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, extends

So I want my main class to extend both JFrame and JPanel. How would I do this?

For example:

```
public class mainClass extends JFrame {
//code here
}
```

How would I also extend JPanel for that same class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't do it. Jpanel and jframe are both classes and java doesn't support multiple inheritance of classes. Only one class and many interfaces.

Comment: **Don't** extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one.  Only extend `JPanel` if you are adding or changing functionality.  Are you doing either of those things?  If so, what specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not support multiple inheritance. Possible solutions include coding an inner class in your main class that extends JPanel and then another inner class that extends JFrame. You can also just code two separate (not-inner) classes that extend the respective classes as that is the common approach I would use.

Answer (score 6):

> How to extend JFrame and JPanel in a main class?

Let me answer you by asking a question:

Can a son have two fathers in a the same time? NO, because we don't know who is the real father, but after DNA testing you know who is the real one.

In java, there is no DNA testing, sorry for that, therefore, multiple inheritance not allowed.

In your case, if the class extended from both `JFrame` and `JPanel`, what will be the behavior of this class, panel or frame?

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't. Java does not support multiple inheritance so you can't have a class which extends two different classes.

And in your situation I don't see why you would need a class which extends both `JFrame` and `JPanel` as they're two different things used for different purposes.

Maybe you simply need to be able to define your own frame and panel inside a single class? You can use inner classes for this:

```
class MainClass {
  static class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    ..
  }

  static class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    ..
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> So I want my main class to extend both JFrame and JPanel. How would I
>   do this?

**You can't**, Java only support simple inheritance.

And in my opinion concrete inheritance is dangerous if you don't use 'properly' Cause you can break object principles and contracts (Liskov Substitution principle, Single Responsibility Principle), difficult to maintain etc.

So the real question is why you need to extend `JFrame` and `JPanel`?

You sure can achieve what you want to do using another techniques.
For example,

Composition.

```
public class MyClass{

private JPanel panel;
private JFrame frame;

}
```

If you need to override some specific behaviour for example `paintComponent` in JPanel you can do (anonymous class)

```
{
//in some part
panel = new JPanel(){

 @Override 
 public void paintComponent(Graphics gr){
     super.paintComponent(gr);
     //your code
 }

}

}
```

Or make an inner class

```
public class MyClass{

private class MyJPanel extends JPanel{

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

JFrame and JPanel are classes so you cant directly inherit two classes at same time.

First you create JPanel and add the components to it.

Then set the Jpanel to JFrame (JFrame contains a JRootPane as its only child.)

class Sample extends JFrame{

```
Sample (){
    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    conent.add(comp1);
    conent.add(comp2);
    ................. //comp1,comp2 are your JButton or JTextBox or JLabel ...etc..
    .................
    setContentPane(content);
    setVisible(true);
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {

   }
```

}